# Cannot post array using jquery $.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I can't seem to be able to post an array using jQuery.post function. It throws an 500 Internal Server error code.

This is the actual jQuery post:

```
function ChangeAllStatuses(statusId) {    
var ids = [];
var i = 0;
var hiddenIds = $('[name|="serialIds"]');
hiddenIds.each(function () {
    ids[i++] = $(this).val();
});
$.post(
    ChangeAllStatusesURL,
    {
        serialIds: ids,  //this is the array
        statusId: statusId
    },
    function (data) {
        if (data.indexOf('Error') == 0)
            $('#message').html(data);
        else
            location.reload();
    })
```

}

and this is the controller action that expects the post data:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangeAllStatuses(int[] serialIds, int statusId)
    {
        string result = service.ChangeAllStatuses(serialIds, statusId);
        return Content(result);
    }
```

Comment: 500 server error doesn't mean anything other than "server error".  You'll need to debug this on the server.

Comment: @Archer, serialIds reaches the server null, and I don't understand why; the ids variable is not null, when I set the post parameter using this variable, ids is an array containing 2 int values.

Comment: When you debug the post using Developer Tools, do you see the serialIds parameter in the POST (meaning the client is sending the values to the server)?

Comment: Try no to use a shorthand function. Replace it with regular `$.ajax({ traditional: true })` and set the `traditional` parameter to `true`.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta, where more exactly can I see the parameters that are sent with the POST request ?

Comment: If you are using either IE or Chrome, just hit F12 to bring up the developer tools. Then click on the 'Network' tab. With this tab opened, submit your form and you'll be able to see the POST

Answer (score 0):

MVC requires a specific way of serializing the data.

use `$ajax` with the `traditional` flag.

This will serialize the data differently. Note that this doesn't cope well with complex arrays, for example (from the [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) documentation):

```
// <=1.3.2: ( = traditional)
$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }); // "a=2&a=3&a=4"
// >=1.4:
$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }); // "a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4"

// <=1.3.2: ( = traditional)
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5 } ] });
// "a=[object+Object]&d=3&d=4&d=[object+Object]"

// >=1.4:
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5 } ] });
// "a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d[]=3&d[]=4&d[2][e]=5"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not formatting them right. Instead of .post() use .ajax()

```
$.ajax({
   url: '~/myUrl/',
       data: {
           serialIds: ids,
           statusId: statusId
       },
       type: "POST"
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply initialised the array like a javascript object and it worked fine:

```
var ids = {};
```